# AbstractMethodError exception while instantiating JavaStreamingContext

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am getting AbstractMethodError  exception while creating a JavaStreamingContext.
My dependency pom is as below; Unable to find the clue , Can anyone suggest whats going wrong here ?

```
    <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus$class.$init$(ListenerBus.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.StreamingListenerBus.(StreamingListenerBus.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler.(JobScheduler.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.(StreamingContext.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.(StreamingContext.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.(JavaStreamingContext.scala:130)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing many versions of Spark here
First of all, if you're using Apache Spark 2.3.1 and kafka 0.10+

I suggest the following :

```
<dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <!-- Keep the same Spark version as before -->
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <!-- Keep the same Spark version as before -->
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <!-- Support for kafka version 0.8 is deprecated as of Spark 2.3.1 and you add the dependencies for kafka 0.10+ above -->
        <version><your_kafka_version_0.10+></version>
    </dependency>
```

It would be nice to know how you build/deploy your application ? according to your runtime environment, you may want to add some scope provided to prevent conflict between the built package and the existing environment.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thsnks I realized , I am mixing versions of spark , scala. As suggested I have defined the scope of spark and scala to arraive at proper libs for my app.